# Ist der Satz "Ein Haus, dass die Zeiten überdauert" aus dieser Anzeige grammatikalisch korrekt? Falls ja, warum?

Tags: spelling, pronoun

In einer Anzeige in der taz steht:

> Ein Mensch, der uns ähnelt,
> Ein Haus, dass die Zeiten überdauert.

Ist die Orthographie *dass* (mit Doppel-*s*) hier korrekt?  Ich dachte, dass *das* nur mit einem *s* geschrieben wird, wenn es als Artikel oder Relativpronomen verwendet wird. Und hier handelt es sich ja um ein Relativpronomen.  Als Konjunktion (*wetten dass ...*) schreibt man *dass* mit Doppel-*s*.  Heißt das, dass *dass* hier als *das* geschrieben werden soll und dass die Orthographie hier falsch ist?  Oder ist es doch richtig, und wenn ja, warum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wie Du erklärst, sollte in dem Satz das Relativpronomen „das“ stehen.

Comment: Eine Begründung würde die Antwort verbessern.

Comment: @DavidVogt, steht schon alles in der Frage.